# Is it necessary to lookup entity first to populate navigation property of another entity before saving it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, navigation-properties

Previously I was saving a user this way:

```
context.User.Add(
  new User
  {
      GroupId = groupId
  });
await context.SaveChangesAsync()
```

But then introduced a navigation property for Group so save it now this way:

```
context.User.Add(
  new User
  {
      Group = await db.Groups.FindAsync(groupId)
  });
await context.SaveChangesAsync()
```

Is it possible to avoid this db lookup for each navigation property before saving the parent object? Like this:

```
context.User.Add(
  new User
  {
      Group = new Group { GroupId = groupId }
  });
await context.SaveChangesAsync()
```

It throws an entity validation exception:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'name', table 'Project.dbo.Groups'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

So I'm wondering is there any workarounds

Comment: What exception is it throwing?

Comment: How about `user.ID_Group = groupID` i.e setting the value of the FK rather than the navigation property? It doesn't work anymore?

Comment: @WiktorZychla: I don't have it mapped anymore to encourage to use the navigation property and make it clearer. Probably it will work but I'm looking for a way to do not map it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just keep it the way you had before.

```
context.User.Add(
  new User
  {
      GroupId = groupId
  });
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

If you step through your original code, you will notice the navigational property will be available (via lazy load) after you SaveChanges.

Comment: I don't have GroupId mapped, EF was throwing an exception that "field is already been mapped" and I removed it. Also to encourage others to use the navigation properties instead,

Comment: It's best to keep the FKs mapped because it allows you to setup a relationship without a lookup.